# How to use USB over Remote Connection to a Virtual Machine

Tags: usb, vmware, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to do mobile application development (BlackBerry, Android) on a virtual machine. My idea is that no matter what desktop I'm on I can open a remote connection to the virtual machine and have my mobile development environment ready. The problem is that I would like to deploy code to the mobile device as if it were physically connected to the virtual machine. Ideally the devices will be plugged in to the client machine that is creating the remote connection.

I'm currently using VMWare workstation to manage my virtual machines, I've done a bit of research to see what the best solution for connecting my usb devices over the network is.

There are a multitude of pricey USB over network solutions that may or may not work for what I'm trying, but I would like to avoid those. I would be interested in a free open source solution where both the usb host and usb client are windows machines. This is close to what I am looking for http://usbip.sourceforge.net/, but you can't host a device from Windows.

It appears that I may be able to do this with a Hyper-V VM and RemoteFX through Microsoft RDC, but I would like this to work on my existing VMWare VM.

The quickest solution I've found is a network usb hub that would allow me to connect the devices over the network, but this would force me to be attached to the hub which is a problem if more people come on my project.

Ideally I'm looking for an existing software solution to my problem. Any suggestions?

Also can anyone confirm this would work in Hyper-V using RemoteFX?

Comment: I'm aware that it's convoluted, but could you create a Linux VM at your Windows host, connect your device there, and use *that VM* as your usbip server?

Comment: @Piskvor I thought of that, I may try it, but I'm keeping my hopes up for something a little more elegant.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm looking to do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider porting your VM over to VirtualBox from Sun (now Oracle) they have remote USB support out-of-the-box, and are very stable.

I've ported machines the other way (for work) and it's not difficult.