# Mobile phone from a Client Computer to a Virtual Machine in the vSphere Web Client

Tags: android, mobile, usb, vmware, vsphere

As per [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-879E3BDF-460A-454A-84AF-85019E0B9326.html) it is possible to connect USB devices on a computer and a VM running on a remote server to pick it up through vsphere.

My questions is, how can I know what hardware is compatible with this?

I want to have the Android studio on a server and have the phone plugged to my laptop would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way of doing this natively on VM (yet) but I found a work around, big work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951075/how-to-use-usb-over-remote-connection-to-a-virtual-machine).

In essence create a VM on the computer to server the USB (client) put linux on it and install [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) as server later go to the VM on the ESXi host and install the USB/IP client.